# What exactly does SOFU stand for?

Tags: stack-overflow, discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

[SOFU](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=sofu) stands for Stack Overflow, ... right? But where did the U come from?

Comment: See the glossary: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms -- SO is Stack Overflow, SF is Sever Fault, SU is Super User, combine them to get SOFU

Comment: Needs a Voltron tag.

Comment: getting something closed is not that bad. No need to defend yourself

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User - S[OFU]

Answer (score 11):

**S**tack **O**verflow + **S**erver **F**ault + **S**uper **U**ser == S[OFU], or short SOFU.

SOFU stands for the complete Trilogy, not just Stack Overflow (SO).