# Border bottom alignment issue in trilogy site's account recovery page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, login, account-recovery

There is some alignment issue in the following trilogy or [S[OFU]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44127/312043) site's account recovery page.
The **Sign up** link's border bottom is missing.

You can find the issue in the following links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery
- https://serverfault.com/users/account-recovery
- https://superuser.com/users/account-recovery

Can be able to reproduce this in the following browsers:

Firefox: `49.0.1`
Chrome: `51.0.2704.103 m`
OS: `Windows 8`

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Border bottom is missing]

**Update:** The border bottom issue is in Stack Apps account recovery page too. There extra border is displaying under the **Login** tab.

- https://stackapps.com/users/account-recovery

> [image: Stack Apps]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the recent design change, the account recovery page UI also changed. So the issue has been resolved.

Screenshot for the new UI:

> [image: Account recovery page]