# Tab underline issue for Russian Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, design, russian-stackoverflow

[Main page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) of *Stack Overflow на русском* (while opened in private mode) contains underline issue for tabs.

Appears in FF and Chrome on different scale factrors:

- FF 100%

  > [image: 100%FF]
- FF 80%

  > [image: 80%FF]
- Chrome 90%

  > [image: 90%Chrome]

Comment: We don't support "different scale factors", only 100%.

Comment: @Oded ok, look at the FF only.

Comment: Might be related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285738/bottom-bar-alignment-issue-in-trilogy-sites-account-recovery-page

Comment: @ShadowWizard in this case it's only appears for ruSO site (ptSO, esSO and even jpSO look fine).