# Selected tab is not highlighted in the Profile tab - Questions/Answers section

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

In some of the Stack Exchange sites (like [S[OFU]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44127/312043), MSE and some more), when we are navigating to the Profile page, in the Questions/Answers section we can see the tabs are highlight with any one of the option. As in the image below:

[image: Highlighted]

But for some other sites, when we navigate to the Profile page we didn't see any highlighted tab. As in the image below:

[image: Not highlight]

After changing the tabs selection also the selected tab is not highlighting.

The following and some more sites has the highlight issue:

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/86/shog9
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/115/shog9
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/63/shog9
https://android.stackexchange.com/users/3812/shog9

When I inspect an element for this tabs, I see the code below:

```
<span id="post-filters">
    <a>All</a>
    <a data-type="1" class="active">Questions</a>
    <a data-type="2">Answers</a>
</span>
```

`class="active"` is applied to the tabs for highlighting, looks like the

```
 a.active { border-bottom: 1px solid #colorcode; }
```

is missing in the CSS file.

---

**Update:** Now the selected tab highlighting is not working in S[OFU] and MSE sites too.

Comment: Best account to test :-) But sharing personnel information should not be done I think. Better you can use the Community profile link

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. I'll take a look.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[Is “Top Posts” using the wrong active class?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349756)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue (and sorry for taking 2 months to correct this!) This affected all community themes. It was caused from not applying the selected styles properly to `.active`. This has been corrected, as demonstrated here:

[image]

These changes will roll out to all other SE communities in the next production build.

Comment: Thanks for the response. After the next build, let me check and accept this answer.

Comment: Not sure if this rolled out or not but on [math.se] this seems to be even more broken... the selected section is now white text, which can't be discerned from the background.

Comment: @Catija Are you referring to the issue mentioned in [this Meta.MathSE post?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26426/tabs-questions-and-answers-on-user-profile-arent-readable-when-selected)

Comment: Ah, indeed! Glad to see it's being handled :D